# How to insert <input type="text" placeholder="writer"> with CSS without using the input tag itself?

Tags: django, html, css

```
 <div class="col-sm-2">
 {{ adminform.form.writer }}
</div>
```

In the above code there is no input tag how to insert placeholder named 'writer' using css?

Comment: There's lot of ways. Can I see your required UI?

Comment: You need to change the form.py. Add that code where you created this and I will tell you what you need to change

Comment: I have added the code already

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you will not get input placeholder feature in **div**. Simply You give a placeholder if the data is **empty in div**.
add a placeholder attribute in your element.

```
<div class="col-sm-2" placeholder="Write"> {{ adminform.form.writer }}</div>
```

In css you can check **:empty** and get value from attribute

```
div[placeholder]:empty:after {
 content: attr(placeholder);
}
```

Hope this will help you.